# Why isn't the arc length of $\cos x$ equal to $\pm \sin x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, derivatives, arc-length

The arc length of some function $f(x)$ is given by $$L=\int{\sqrt{1+f'\left(x\right)^2}}dx$$
Plugging $\cos x$ in for $f$ and using basic algebra, this simplifies as follows
$$L=\int{\sqrt{1+\cos'\left(x\right)^2}}dx$$
$$L=\int{\sqrt{1-\sin\left(x\right)^2}}dx$$
$$L=\int{\sqrt{\cos\left(x\right)^2}}dx$$
$$L=\int{\pm\cos\left(x\right)}dx$$
$$L=\pm\sin x$$
Obviously this is wrong. The real answer involves elliptic integrals, but my question is, why does this approach give such an incorrect result? What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$(-\sin x)^2 \ne -(\sin x)^2$$

Comment: For OP: Also note that $-\sin(x)^2$ is interpreted as $-(\sin(x)^2)$ because of order of operations.

Comment: I figured it was something simple like this. *facepalm* Thanks, Kenny. :)